# win32com - Write String values in Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm using win32com to write some dates that I receive from a database, and my problem is that I'm having values like '01' and in Excel is just '1' - not '01'.
Example:

```
    b = row[1] # b has the value 01
    c = "-"+b+"-"  # c has value -01-
    sheet.Cells(1,1).Value = b  # I have in Excel '1' ; I've try with str(b), c - but is the same
```

How can I fix this, to have in Excel the value recognize as a String, in this case - 01?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `sheet.Cells(1,1)` have an attribute something like `format` where you can change it to string/text?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks eumiro for the point

I've found the solution - I'm formating the cells to contain String values:

```
range = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(100, 2) )
range.NumberFormat = '@'
```

I'm doing this before I'm puting the values in cells and it works ok, now in Excel cells I have String values.